# Power and work of tension force of a rotating body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, work, rotation, power

Suppose that we have a body rotating on a massless string with a uniform velocity. What can we say about the work done by this tension. Moreover, what is the power related to this work.

I do not have a problem with power, since it is a dot product of a tension force and a velocity vector which are perpendicular. So it is equal to zero.

The question I have is what about work. Is it also zero? Because at every point on the circle, displacement is also perpendicular to the tension force.
Is this thinking correct or there is a lack of something which I do not see.

Comment: If power is zero, how can work be non-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tension is balancing the centrifugal force and  is directed towards the centre of the circle. The angle between it and velocity vector is 90° so W=Fx(cos∅) and ∅=90°, so W=0.
Since P=W/t => P is also 0.